# fgets function is not reading the first character in the input

Tags: c, linux, call, system, fgets

Here is my code and the system call works when there is just one word with no space or anything between (like enter...).

For example when I use "pwd" the call works but when I use something like `ls -l` or let's say "cd file1 file2" it erases the first character and doesn't take into account anything after the space.

So when I write "cd file1 file2" only the "d" of "cd" is left. What can i do to prevent that ?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "Expert_mode.h"

void Expert_mode()
{
    printf("Your are now in Expert mode, You are using a basic Shell (good luck) \nWe added the commands 'read_history', 'leave' and 'Easter_egg'. \n");

    int a = 0;
    while(a == 0)
    {

        char* line;

        getchar();

        printf("Choose a command : \n");

        line = malloc(100*sizeof(char));

        fgets(line, 100, stdin);

        if(strcoll(line, "leave") == 0)
        {
            a = 1;
        }
        else if(strcoll(line, "read_history") == 0)
        {
            //read_history();
        }
        else if(strcoll(line, "Easter_egg") == 0)
        {
           // Easter_egg();
        }
        else
        {
            system(line);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are going to allocate a fixed-size buffer, why not use an array? Then you won't have the memory leak.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because you have `getchar();` call *before* `fgets()` call. So it consumes the first character and only the rest of the input is read by `fgets()`. Remove it.

Also, note that [`fgets()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgetc.3.html) would read the trailing newline as well, if buffer space is available. You would want to trim it.

You can use [`strchr()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strchr.3.html) to remove the newline, if present:

```
fgets(line, 100, stdin);
char *p = strchr(line, '\n');
if (p) *p = 0;
```

Comment: Thank you so much ^^ but how do I use the code you wrote and why exactly ? Sorry for the stupid questions I'm quite a newbie in coding

Comment: @LucaS-c Just copy-paste the last 2 lines from my answer after the fgets call in your code. It's that simple :)

Comment: Thanks a lot man I understand what this does now I feel stupid ><

Comment: Better `line[strcspn(line, "\n")] = 0;` to remove the `'\n'`.